# how to find Load balancer IP Address from host

Tags: linux, load-balancing

[image]I am on of the linux server and I have to identify the Loadbalancer IP address to which this linux server is added to.
As per the image , I am on one of the Linux Server and trying to find the IP address of LB or IP address from where traffic is coming to Linux Server .

Comment: What type of loadbalancer is it? What platform? Question is too vague.

Comment: Hi JazzCat, this is virtual LB and a VIP is configured.

Answer (score -1):

In server after logged in.

You can use command

"**ifconfig**"

But if you have load balancer alias name or IP address you can use 'ping website/ip'

IP address is not fixed for Load Balancer because load balancer provide multiple IPs by location and zone.

You use '**getaddrinfo**' command and get information.

Also you can use **nslookup [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**

If you are using AWS EC2 load balancer you can get IP address using AWS API.

Comment: Thank you Abhishek for sharing the details . Let me try getaddrinfo . However , I added one image . I am on one of the linux host trying to find the IP address of LB .

Comment: Who is your LB provider or cloud hosting provider ?

Comment: You can find A record using dnschecker https://dnschecker.org/ A record is IP address of load balancer

Comment: This is local setup . No cloud is used.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).